# How to perform different actions depending on validation error outcome in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a line in the user model that validates the following for emails upon sign up

```
validates :email, presence: true, 
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                length: { maximum: 254 }
```

If there are errors, I render the sign up page ('new') with error messages:
In the controller:

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to root_path
else
  render 'new'
end
```

In the view:

```
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
      <p><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</p>
      <ul>
         <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
      </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

However, if the email address the user enters an email address that is not unique, I want to redirect to a new page. Is there any way I can do this? How do I modify the controller to do something different for this specific type of error?

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveRecord Model invalid?](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M000305) seems to be what you are looking for

```
// in controller
redirect_to your_path if @user.errors.invalid?(:email)
```

Comment: thanks! I only want to do that if the email is not unique though, for example if the email address was not valid, I'd just display an error message explaining why, but not redirect to a new page.